# Use jQuery to target the bottom TD in a table column

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Ok, so this is the table markup:

```
    -------------------------------
    heading1 | heading2 | heading3|
    -------------------------------
    <TABLE CONTENT>
    -----------------------------
    column1 | column2 | column3 |
    -----------------------------
```

Not great i know but the principle is this: i need to target column1, column2 and column3.

So i can use jQuery to do this: set heading1 as column1's HTML and set heading2 as  column2's HTML etc...

But i'm not sure how to relate heading1 to column1 etc...

Thanks

Comment: when you say "set heading1 as column1's HTML" you want to add the content of heading 1 to column 1 etc?

Comment: Replace it. What i'm trying to get across (in a roundabout way) is know the value of a "column-x" in relation to "heading-x". if that makes any sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of headings and columns are same, then u may use this:
Assuming headings to be copied are assigned class='source' and target rows (of course first row of column) as `class='target'`=>

```
var dummy=Array(), ctr=0;
dummy=$('.target');
$('.source').each(function()
{
$(dummy[ctr++]).html($(this).html());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want:

```js
$headings = $('#myTable tr:first th');
$('#myTable tr:last th').each(function(i) { $(this).html($headings.eq(i).html()) });
```

But, actually, for copying header you may simply append it to the bottom of table:

```js
$('#myTable').append($('#myTable tr:first').clone());
```

The only thing I can add - it would be better to use thead and tfoot for header/footer of table, in this case you will have more comfortable for reading code and easier and faster header/footer row selection.